# Java, URL output different in java output

Tags: java, url, unicode, utf-8, uri

I have a question about URI and URL
when i pass a url is work good but result is worst need help!!

as my code look like this.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class isms {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {


       String user = new String ("boo");
       String pass = new String ("boo");
       String dstno = new String("60164038811"); //You are going compose a message to this destination number.
       String msg = new String("你的哈达哈达!"); //Your message over here
       int type = 2; //for unicode change to 2, normal will the 1.
       String sendid = new String("isms"); //Malaysia does not support sender id yet.

            // Send data
            URI myUrl = new URI("http://www.isms.com.my/isms_send.php?un=" + user + "&pwd=" + pass 
                + "&dstno=" + dstno + "&msg=" + msg + "&type=" + type + "&sendid=" + sendid);
            URL url = new URL(myUrl.toASCIIString());

            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            // Get the response
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                // Print the response output...
                System.out.println(line);
            }      
            rd.close();

            System.out.println(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
}
```

the output in web is different..
on my java output is

> 你的哈达哈达!

but on my the site is

> ÄãµÄ¹þ´ï¹þ´ï!

Help!!

Comment: Can you give more details on what are you using to print this on your website?

Comment: encoding is your problem, you have to use another encoding that accept that asiatic letters.. by the way don't use `new String` instead use just "" and psw shouldn't be pass in `GET METHOD`

Comment: @raygozag the website is a message service, when you change the message it will send to the destination number.

Comment: @nachokk the pass is work fine cause it just will check within the url. got any way to encode the asiatic letters?

Comment: no idea, can be in 2 places, when you pass the url check `myUrl.toASCIIString()` if it's correct, or when you read may be it's the encoding you have to put some chinese encoding when you read the input stream

Comment: @nachokk it didnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

```
String user = new String ("boo");
```

You don't need to (and shouldn't) do `new String` in Java—`String user = "boo";` is fine.

```
String msg = new String("你的哈达哈达!");
```

Writing non-ASCII characters in your source means that you have to get the `-encoding` flag to `javac` to match the encoding you have saved your text files with. It is possible you have saved the .java file as UTF-8 but not configured your build environment to use UTF-8 at compile time.

If you are not sure that you've got this right, you can use ASCII-safe `\u` escapes in the meantime:

```
String msg = "\u4F60\u7684\u54C8\u8FBE\u54C8\u8FBE!";  // 你的哈达哈达!
```

Finally:

```
URI myUrl = new URI("http://www.isms.com.my/isms_send.php?un=" + user + "&pwd=" + pass 
            + "&dstno=" + dstno + "&msg=" + msg + "&type=" + type + "&sendid=" + sendid);
```

When you're putting a URI together you should URL-escape each of the parameters you include in the string. Otherwise any `&` or other invalid character in the value will break the query. This also allows you to choose what charset is used to create the query string.

```
String enc = "UTF-8";
URI myUrl = new URI("http://www.isms.com.my/isms_send.php?" +
    "un=" + URLEncoder.encode(user, enc) +
    "&pwd=" + URLEncoder.encode(pass, enc) +
    "&dstno=" + URLEncoder.encode(dstno, enc) +
    "&msg=" + URLEncoder.encode(msg, enc) +
    "&type=" + URLEncoder.encode(Integer.toString(type), enc) +
    "&sendid=" + URLEncoder.encode(sendid, enc)
);
```

What the right value for `enc` is depends on the service you are connecting to, but `UTF-8` is a good guess.